# import scss file with Storybook

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, storybook

I'm currently facing an issue with Storybook. Everything is working great in my app, with webpack. Storybook seems to have issue with my configuration.

Here's my webpack.config.js :

```
module.exports = {
   entry: './index.js',
   output: {
   path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
   filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module: {
   loaders: [
   {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: __dirname
   },
   {
      test: /\.scss$/,
         use: [
         {loader: "style-loader"}, 
         {loader: "css-loader"},
         {loader: "sass-loader",
          options: {
            includePaths: [__dirname]
    }
  }]
},
```

Storybook have issue with parsing the scss file, do I need to create a specific webpack.config.js for Storybook to solve this?

In my main app I'm importing my scss file this way : `import './styles/base.scss'`

Comment: More information is needed to answer your question, such as how are you importing the scss file into your app.

Comment: thanks for notyfing me that.I'll complete my question

Comment: there is a section on the documents for your use case https://storybook.js.org/configurations/custom-webpack-config/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try to solve it following the documentation steps.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It worked just by adding a webpack.config.js quite similar to my existing one :

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    module: {
     rules: [
     {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../')
     },
     {  test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
        include: __dirname
     },
     {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            name: 'fonts/[hash].[ext]',
            limit: 5000,
            mimetype: 'application/font-woff'
          }
         }
     },
     {
       test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|png)$/,
       use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: 'fonts/[hash].[ext]'
          }
       }
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For those running storybook on Create React App, adding `MiniCssExtractPlugin` to `.storybook/webpack.config.jon` solved my problem loading sass files:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = function({ config }) {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../')
  });

  config.plugins.push(new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '[name].css' }))

  return config;
};
```

[Credits to Nigel Sim!](https://blog.nigelsim.org/2019/10/26/debugging-storybook-angular-customisation/)

Comment: Wow, I spent hours looking for a sass solution and this is the only solution that worked for me. I'm running Gatsby on top of React.

Comment: This works if you run the Storybook, but fails on build! - https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/11052

Answer (score 6):

**SCSS preset for Storybook**

**Basic usage**

```
npm i -D @storybook/preset-scss css-loader sass sass-loader style-loader
```

Then add the following to `.storybook/main.js:`

```
module.exports = {
  addons: ['@storybook/preset-scss'],
};
```

*OR*
**Advanced usage**

You can pass configurations by using Object addon declaration for `@storybook/preset-scss` and adding the configurations under the `options` key. You can pass configurations into the preset's webpack loaders using `styleLoaderOptions`, `cssLoaderOptions`, and `sassLoaderOptions` keys. See documentation for each respective loader to learn about valid options. You can register other addons through the string declaration as normal.

```
module.exports = {
  addons: [
    {
      name: '@storybook/preset-scss',
      options: {
        cssLoaderOptions: {
           modules: true,
           localIdentName: '[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
        }
      }
    },
    // You can add other presets/addons by using the string declaration
    '@storybook/preset-typescript',
    '@storybook/addon-actions',
  ]
}
```

Comment: This simple solution did it for me. I already had sass and loader packages for the main app so just installing and using the `@storybook/preset-scss` was good enough to get the `.scss` imports working.

Answer (score 5):

#### There is simple code for `main.js` in Storybook 6, and it works fine for me!

```html
const path = require('path');

// Export a function. Accept the base config as the only param.
module.exports = {
  stories: [...],
  addons:[...],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // `configType` has a value of 'DEVELOPMENT' or 'PRODUCTION'
    // You can change the configuration based on that.
    // 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.

    // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?url=false', 'sass-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });

    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  },
};
```